# Infinitely many times differentiable function, whose every derivative approaches zero at x boundaries

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Prove that there exist such nondecreasing, infinitely many times differentiable function $f: \Bbb{R}\to[0,1]$ that $f(x)=0$ when $x\le0 $ and $f(x)=1$ when $x\ge1$.

I've come up with necessary condition that derivative of any order has to approach $0$ when $x \to0^+$ and $x \to1^-$, but I can't make any usage of it. I've already tried to fit there some exponential function, but I failed since it would require the argument to be streched, and that didn't go well with initial condition.

Any help and hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\varphi\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ by$$\varphi(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x}&\text{ if }t\geqslant0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Now, let $\displaystyle f(t)=\frac{\varphi(t)}{\varphi(t)+\varphi(1-t)}$.

Comment: Well, I guess that solves both existance and monotonicity problem but how can I show that every derivative of it approaches zero at $0$ and $1$ in other way than simply calculating them?

Comment: @Igor Simply compute $\varphi^{(n)}(0)$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Basically, this uses the fact, for any polynomial function $P(x)$, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{e^x}{P(x)}=0$. It follwos from this that $f^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(1)=0$ for each natural $n$.

Comment: Well, I guess everything is clear for me now, Thank You very much!

Comment: @Igor I'm glad I could help.